# delete all lisbox item using loop

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can i delete all listbox item using a loop i want to also delete all files in  each location

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
        path1 = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        path2 = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Dim fullpath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(path1, path2)
        Kill(fullpath)
    Next
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want to remove all the ***selected*** items, or simply ***all*** items? If it's the later just use `Clear`.

Comment: When you delete the item at 0 (zero) everything shifts, then you move up to index 1 (one), skipping the one that just shifted.  This repeats at each index.  Use Clear() as suggested by others, or iterate **backwards** to avoid this problem.

Comment: i want to delete all items and its individual files.Please help me

Comment: loop from `(Count-1) to 0 Step -1` but delete **Items** to delete them all and delete the files in the loop

Answer (score 5):

Loop version:

```
For i As Integer = (listbox1.Items.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
 listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

Simple version:

```
listbox1.Items.Clear()
```

To remove/process only selected indexes:

```
'get list of selected items
Dim SelectedItems = lsb.SelectedIndices
'collection of indexes to process/remove
Dim sortedSelectedItems As New List(Of Integer)
For Each i In SelectedItems
  sortedSelectedItems.Add(CInt(i))
Next
'sort them from lowest to highest so we remove in correct order
sortedSelectedItems.Sort()
For i = sortedSelectedItems.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  Dim file As String = lsb.Items(sortedSelectedItems(i)).ToString
  'do somethign with file
  'remove item
  lsb.Items.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

Comment: @OkwuPrecious, I updated to handle selected items too